# How do I see number of downloads of my unmanaged package?

Tags: unmanaged-package

We supply an unmanaged package of reports and dashboards to our customers, is there somewhere I can see total number of downloads?

Comment: Is this through the AppExchange that the package is provided?

Comment: @DaveHumm no, we just have a direct link to it..

Answer (score 0):

If you're a partner you could use the LMA application that salesforce provides

https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/appinnovators/License_Management_App

You have to request it through support

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_lma.meta/workbook_lma/lma_install_app.htm

Other than that I don't know if there's a way for developers to see number of downloads of unmanaged unlisted packages